# Prevent new rows from being inserted when max records reached?

Tags: php

I have an SQL table where I want the max numbers of records to be 8.

I have a form to capture input via PHP and I thought I had an error handler that operates by counting the number of records in the table and, through an IF statement, punts the user back with an error if there are >= 8 records:

```
<?php

// Connect to database

include_once 'db_connect.php';

// Check for form action and submitted fields

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $artist = $_POST["artist"];
    $song = $_POST["song"];
    $link = $_POST["link"];

    // Link to external error handling functions

    require_once 'functions.php';

    // Check for empty fields

    if (emptyFields($artist, $song, $link) !== false) {
        header("location: index.php?error=empty");
        exit();
    }

    // Check if record already exists

    if (songExists($conn, $link, $song) !== false) {
        header("location: index.php?error=duplicate");
        exit();
    }

    // Check if link is valid

    if (invalidLink($link) !== false) {
        header("location: index.php?error=invalidlink");
        exit();
    }

    // Check if table records are greater than or equal to 8

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Num FROM songs";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if ($dbName['Num'] >= 8) {
        header("location: index.php?error=maxreached");
        exit();
    }

    // If no errors from above, add to table

    addSong($conn, $artist, $song, $link);

}
else {
    header("location: index.php?error=none");
    exit();
}
```

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Song Submission</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="sb_process2.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
            <input type="text" name="artist">
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="song">
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="link">
            <br>
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit Song</button>
        </form>

        <?php
            if (isset($_GET["error"])) {
                if ($_GET["error"] == "empty") {
                    echo "<p>Please enter all fields.</p>";
                }
                else if ($_GET["error"] == "duplicate") {
                    echo "<p>This song has already been submitted.</p>";
                }
                else if ($_GET["error"] == "invalidlink") {
                    echo "<p>Please enter a valid URL for the Spotify link.</p>";
                }
                else if ($_GET["error"] == "none") {
                    echo "<p>Song added!</p>";
                }
            }
        ?>
```

I tested for my first 3 error cases and all are operating as planned (they route back with an error "code"). However, if I try to submit an entry without any errors, I just get a blank page. I ran the code through a simple PHP syntax checker and it didn't come up with any errors.

Comment: And your question is? Why it works that as long as there is no output as there really is no output?

Comment: Not sure what you’re saying? It doesn’t work for me… it doesn’t allow me to add new records — it doesn’t seem to be processing anything as after I click submit on my form, my browser hangs on my form handler PHP.

Comment: Well you wrote in the question that the error handling does work. If you have no additional error handling for inserting nor any other output when inserting, it clearly does work even you declare it as not-working. Perhaps you should make that more clear in your question so that if you get comments you're actually able to understand what those are "saying"?

Comment: If you read my question all the way through, I'm asking how to prevent more than 8 rows being inserted into my database. I said all my other error handling is working, except for the portion that is checking if there are more than 8 records.